# Choosing .NET version when injecting code with Reflexil

Tags: .net, version, decompiling, reflexil

I have a .NET dll file with no source code that was compiled with .NET 2.0.  Needed to add a few fields to this dll so I used Reflexil (in conjuction with JustDecompile). I used the inject field option with Reflexil. When I saved and reloaded, I checked the references and found that 'mscorlib 4.0.0.0' is now added. I would like Reflexil to inject the field, but not add the .NET 4.0 dependency.  I looked all over for settings to have it recompile as .NET 2.0, but I do no see this anywhere.

When editing functions, you ARE able to choose what compiler to use as an option (2.0, 3.5, 4.0). I would like this same option when adding a field.

Does anyone have any insight to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Reflexil v1.9. It was related to an improper corlib type import.